# Where can I buy iMovie that is compatible with SL?

Tags: snow-leopard, mac-appstore, imovie

I just upgraded my macbook to SL and wanted to upgrade iMovie too. But the system requirement for the version available on App Store is 10.7.4 or later. Where can I purchase one that would work on a SL 10.6.8? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that on [ebay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=ilife%2009&_sacat=&_odkw=imovie&_osacat=0) you can buy iLife '09. If you look at the iLife '09 tech specs, you can see this:

> **Software:**
>   
> Mac OS X v10.5.6 or later.

So that should work for you if you have SL. iLife '09 is also available on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0014X5XEK).

Comment: Thank you for the links. I didn't intend to buy the whole set, but guess I can't purchase iMovie individually?

Comment: @vul3 - The only ways you could bet it individually would be to go through illegitimate channels (torrents), so no I guess. Sorry. It's a marketing ploy by Apple to make you spend money on the entire set.

Comment: I see, think I'll just pay for it then! At least it's cheaper than Mac Box Set...thanks again!